# Draw in a surface and rotate with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to mimic in Python some behavior available in JS with the command context.rotate(angle).

I have the following code below:

```
import pygame
import math
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
RED = pygame.color.THECOLORS['red']
WHITE = pygame.color.THECOLORS['white']
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
surface = pygame.Surface((50, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
rotated_surface = surface
rect = surface.get_rect()
ax = int(screen_width / 2)
ay = int(screen_height / 2)
angle = 0
print("Size of the screen ({}, {})".format(screen_width, screen_height))
print("Center of the screen ({}, {})".format(ax, ay))
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 12)

pygame.display.set_caption("Test rotate")

main_loop = True
amplifier = 200


def calculate_angle(mouse_position):
    dx = mouse_position[0] - ax
    dy = mouse_position[1] - ay
    return np.arctan2(dy,dx)

while main_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            main_loop = False

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = (calculate_angle(pos) * 180)/math.pi
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    rotated_surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, -angle)
    rect = rotated_surface.get_rect(center = (ax, ay))
    screen.blit(rotated_surface, (rect.x, rect.y))
    pygame.draw.line(rotated_surface, WHITE, (ax,ay), (ax+20, ay), 1)
    pygame.draw.line(rotated_surface, WHITE, (ax+10,ay-10), (ax+20, ay), 1)
    pygame.draw.line(rotated_surface, WHITE, (ax+10,ay+10), (ax+20, ay), 1)
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(30)


pygame.quit()
```

I'm drawing an arrow and want to rotate it based on where the mouse is located on the screen. I can of course redraw my lines everytime doing some sine, cosine calculations, but that's painful. I thought surfaces could help me here, and in fact, it works with the rectangle that perfectly rotates. But drawing my lines into the surface doesn't work.

So, I guess I'm misundertanding what surfaces are for, or maybe I'm coding something wrongly and there's a better way to do that. Note that if I replace rotated_surface by screen in my draw.line instructions, the arrow does get drawn on screen, but will never rotate.

Any thoughts (beside using image/sprite ;))?

Thanks,

Comment: Call me out on this, But I think you're supposed to do [pygame.transform](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) after you've put things onto the surface? `A Surface transform is an operation that moves or resizes the pixels.` meaning there has to be pixels in there to be transformed to begin with. And the return value is `All these functions take a Surface to operate on and return a new Surface with the results.`. Meaning whatever you blit onto that surface, is post transform. So move it after the `pygame.draw.line` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks Torxed for the suggestion. I tried that already and it doesn't work. Just the black rectangle appears an rotates as the mouse moves around the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing the arrow lines outside of the surface area. The top left coordinates of each surface are (0, 0) so they all have their own (local) coordinate system. Since you're using the screen's center coords to draw the lines, the arrow won't be drawn in the visible surface area.

I'd draw the lines onto the original surface ahead of the while loop using the local coords and then just rotate it and get a new rect inside of the loop.

```
import math
import pygame


pygame.init()

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
GRAY = pygame.color.THECOLORS['gray50']
WHITE = pygame.color.THECOLORS['white']
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # A rect with the size of the screen.
surface = pygame.Surface((50, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
# surface.fill((0, 50, 150))  # Fill the surface to make it visible.
# Use the local coordinate system of the surface to draw the lines.
pygame.draw.line(surface, WHITE, (0, 0), (25, 0), 1)
pygame.draw.line(surface, WHITE, (0, 0), (25, 25), 1)
pygame.draw.line(surface, WHITE, (0, 0), (0, 25), 1)
# I rotate it so that the arrow is pointing to the right (0° is right).
surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, -135)
rect = surface.get_rect()
angle = 0
# If you're using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings.
print(f"Size of the screen {screen.get_size()}")
print(f"Center of the screen {screen_rect.center}")

def calculate_angle(mouse_position):
    dx = mouse_position[0] - screen_rect.centerx
    dy = mouse_position[1] - screen_rect.centery
    return math.atan2(dy, dx)

main_loop = True
while main_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # You shouldn't use `pygame.key.get_pressed` in the event loop.
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT
            or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            main_loop = False

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.degrees(calculate_angle(pos))
    screen.fill(GRAY)
    # Now just rotate the original surface and get a new rect.
    rotated_surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, -angle)
    rect = rotated_surface.get_rect(center=(screen_rect.center))
    screen.blit(rotated_surface, rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(30)


pygame.quit()
```

I've also tried to improve a few more things (check out the comments).

Comment: Of course! The coordinate system :) Thanks skrx, very much appreciated. I got it now.